# BottomSheet is NOT showing imageView when its running but shows in preview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I made xml file for my bottom sheet, everything works nice it shows texts but it is not showing images although in my preview I have imageViews, however when I run the app the images disappear.

Here is part of my xml code of Bottom Sheet:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/trip_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carModel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:text="@string/white_cobalt_textView"
        android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/licensePlate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.20"
        android:text="01 | A 717 CB"
        android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/callingBtn"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/call_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bnt_call" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**I am using BottomSheet in google maps activity, here is xml code where bottom sheet is attached:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_trip_details" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set image with `android:background="@drawable/"` property and it worked!

But I don't know why it was not showing image with property: `app:srcCompat="@drawable/"` or `app:src=""`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `AppCompatImageView` to use `srcCompat`.

Try this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/callingBtn"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/call_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bnt_call" />
```